# Vector of indexes to create matrix by accessing elements of another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

Consider an n-by-k matrix **M** and an p-by-1 vector of indexes  **V** ranging from 1 to n.  How can I create the p-by-k matrix **C** where each row corresponds to the entry of **M** referred to by the value in each row of **V**.

Example

```
M = 1 1
    1 2
    1 3
    1 4
```

and

```
V = 2
    1
    3
```

What I require is the matrix

```
C = 1 2
    1 1
    1 3
```

Comment: What does "refereed" mean in this case?  Can you provide a small numerical example? Your language and description is rather too exotic for me.

Comment: @rayryeng I believe it means "referred".

Comment: This is basic matrix indexing. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85553, specifically the second example in this section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the rows `V` of matrix `M` to a matrix `C`, you would write:

```
C = M(V,:);
```